# How to simulate a reflection of an acoustic wave?

Tags: acoustics, reflection, computational-physics

I'm doing a simulation of the propagation of acoustic waves in space, and I would like to know how I could simulate an infinite plane material with an surface impedance $Z$. I assume that $Z$ is independant of the incident angle, then we know that if a wave $p_1 = A\exp(j(\omega t -\mathbf{k_1}\cdot\mathbf{r}))$ arrives, then there will be a reflected wave $p_2 = AR\exp(j(\omega t - \mathbf{k_2}\cdot \mathbf{r}))$, where $\mathbf{r}$ is the position, and $\mathbf{k_2}$ can be find if we know $\mathbf{k_2}$ using the law of reflection. Finally, here $$ R = \frac{Z\cos(\theta)-Z_0}{Z\cos(\theta)+Z_0}$$

where $\theta$ is the incident angle and $Z_0$ is the impedance of air.

The problem comes when I try to implement this. Indeed, I don't know how I could find efficiently the *direction* of the many incident waves.

To model this situation, I've chosen a finite-difference time-domain method, and use only pressure.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be like any fluid simulation and applying normal reflection boundaries?

Comment: But what are these boundaries?

Comment: Typically, one uses $\vec v\to-\vec v$ and density & pressure the same as the incoming. But this is for fluids, I don't think you'd have velocity in your equation, no?

Comment: I can find the velocity using the differential of the pressure, however you are talking about "the incoming", and the issue stays here. Indeed, I only know the value of pressure in different points, and I can't find the direction of specific waves...

Comment: If you're doing finite difference, you definitely have the incoming because you have a whole grid of points, just use `p[end-1]=p[end]`.

Comment: Wouldn't it only represent total reflection, without absorption?

Comment: Sorry for delay. That particular BC would indeed result in pure reflection, but I suppose that if there's some absorption as well, then you could reduce it with `p[end-1]=(1-Z)*p[end]` (with $0\leq Z\leq1$) or something similar. I've never used such a BC, so that's the best I could offer. If you don't get a response here in the next day or so, you could try over at [scicomp.se].